# net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED on Chrome on Https socket connection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sockets, https

I'm running a **Server-sent Event (SSE)** server over Ingress/Kubernetes/GoogleCloud and it works like a charm. I can run SSE clients over the web and they connect perfectly, start receiving events with no problem.

But there's one ugly bug I can't get it work right, on Chrome browsers after some time I get `net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` error. No matter how many times I run it, I always get it after a few seconds/minutes.

If I run the same client over Firefox, nothing wrongs happens. If I run it using cURL over terminal, nothing wrong happens.

If I decide to run if over Chrome without HTTPS, it works! I'm only getting it when running it through HTTPS and on a Chrome browser.

Has anyone encountered this before? Seems like a ugly bug for me.

Comment: In Ubuntu, I uninstalled OpenVPN https://askubuntu.com/a/1124475 and my issue was solved.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem but it's sporadic.

From the Chromium project source code: OnNetworkChanged will be called when a change occurs to the host computer's hardware or software that affects the route network packets take to any network server. Some examples:

1. A network connection becoming available or going away. For example
       plugging or unplugging an Ethernet cable, WiFi or cellular modem
       connecting or disconnecting from a network, or a VPN tunnel being
       established or taken down.
2. An active network connection's IP address changes.
3. A change to the local IP routing tables.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I went crazy trying to figure out the root of the problem. [Another post](https://superuser.com/questions/747735/regularly-getting-err-network-changed-errors-in-chrome) suggested to turn off IPv6. On Mac, I was able to do `networksetup -setv6off "Wi-Fi"` which seems to have worked.

I do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

For me using a mac system and chrome for a daily basis, I encounter this problem now and then and finally found it might be helpful to solve this problem by just turning off the virtual machines or dock containers whichever can adjust your network configuration.

Maybe not fit for your case but it could be a hint. I saw a lot of people having this kind of issue with chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my case it was a constantly restarting docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is just Chrome. I have been having problems with Chrome getting ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED, but I am also having an issue with Microsoft Teams and uploading files and attachments. In both cases, if I disconnect from OpenVPN they both start working flawlessly. I can even have the ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error page up in Chrome, once I disconnect from the VPN, that page will automatically refresh and load.

I created a support bundle in Teams to separately troubleshoot that issue. When looking through the logs I saw the same error when uploading a file. That's when I knew it wasn't just Chrome.